# How does unqualified name lookup work when using using-declarations?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, name-lookup, using-declaration, name-hiding

Is this ill-formed or well-formed according to the c++ standard?

```
namespace M { struct i {}; }
namespace N { static int i = 1; }
using M::i;
using N::i;
int main() { sizeof (i); }
```

Clang rejects it and GCC accepts it.

According to [namespace.udir-6] (http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.namespace#namespace.udir-6):

> If name lookup finds a declaration for a name in two different
>   namespaces, and the declarations do not declare the same entity and do
>   not declare functions, the use of the name is ill-formed.

How should we interpret this? Remember that each using-declaration are declaring a name by [namespace.udecl]p1 (http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#1):

> A using-declaration introduces a name into the declarative region in
>   which the using-declaration appears.
>
> *using-declaration*:
>      `using typename`<sub>opt</sub> *nested-name-specifier* *unqualified-id* `;`
>
> The member name specified in a using-declaration is declared in the
>   declarative region in which the using-declaration appears. [ Note:
>   Only the specified name is so declared; specifying an enumeration name
>   in a using-declaration does not declare its enumerators in the
>   using-declaration's declarative region.  — end note ] If a
>   using-declaration names a constructor ([class.qual]), it implicitly
>   declares a set of constructors in the class in which the
>   using-declaration appears ([class.inhctor]); otherwise the name
>   specified in a using-declaration is a synonym for a set of
>   declarations in another namespace or class.

So we have 4 declarations of the name i.

Which of these does unqualified name lookup of `i` in `sizeof(i)` find?

Does it only find `using  M::i;` and `using N::i;` which are both in the same namespace (the global namespace) so the program is well-formed?

Or does it only find `struct i {};` and `static int i = 1;` which are in different namespaces so the program is ill-formed?

Or do we have some other alternative?

Comment: I'm sure I saw a question about this lately that concluded there was a bug. Have you searched?

Comment: The question was not exactly the same. This is kind of a follow up question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh, okay. I didn't think of that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[bogdan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31711422/2069064) already has to the answer, but to build on why your intuition is incorrect, you cited:

> If name lookup finds a declaration for a name in **two different namespaces**, and the declarations do not declare the same entity and do not declare functions, the use of the name is ill-formed.

But in the example, we have:

```
namespace M { 
    struct i {};           // declares M::i, entity class type
}
namespace N { 
    static int i = 1;      // declares N::i, entity variable
}
using M::i;                // declares ::i, synonym of M::i
using N::i;                // declares ::i, synonym of N::i
                           // hides (*) the other ::i
int main() { 
    sizeof (i); 
}
```

To elaborate on `(*)`, we have two declaration of `i` in the global namespace `::`. From [basic.scope.hiding]:

> A class name (9.1) or enumeration name (7.2) can be hidden by the name of a variable, data member,
>   function, or enumerator declared in the same scope. If a class or enumeration name and a variable, data
>   member, function, or enumerator are declared in the same scope (in any order) with the same name, the
>   class or enumeration name is hidden wherever the variable, data member, function, or enumerator name is
>   visible.

So with the two `i`s in the same scope, the class is hidden (**irrespective** of the ordering of the *using-declarations*!), and `sizeof(i)` refers to the `::i` that is the synonym of `N::i`. Both `i`s were in the *same* namespace (`::`), which is why your quote doesn't apply. This differs from your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31702956/2069064), where you had *using-directives* instead:

```
using namespace M;
using namespace N;
```

There `i` would be found in two different namespaces, referring to two different non-function entities. Hence, the error. Here, Clang is wrong and GCC is correct.

Answer (score 2):

N4527 [7.3.3p13]:

> Since a *using-declaration* is a declaration, the restrictions on
>   declarations of the same name in the same declarative region (3.3)
>   also apply to *using-declarations*. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> namespace A {
>    int x;
> }
>
> namespace B {
>    int i;
>    struct g { };
>    struct x { };
>    void f(int);
>    void f(double);
>    void g(char);    // OK: hides struct g
> }
>
> void func() {
>    int i;
>    using B::i;      // error: i declared twice
>    void f(char);
>    using B::f;      // OK: each f is a function
>    f(3.5);          // calls B::f(double)
>    using B::g;
>    g(’a’);          // calls B::g(char)
>    struct g g1;     // g1 has class type B::g
>    using B::x;
>    using A::x;      // OK: hides struct B::x
>    x = 99;          // assigns to A::x
>    struct x x1;     // x1 has class type B::x
> }
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

Note the *using-declarations* for the two different `x`s - it's the same case as your example.

---

Your first quote is referring to *using-directives*, not *using-declarations*.

Unqualified name lookup for the `i` in `sizeof(i)` finds the `i`s in the global namespace. Since they are declarations in the same scope, according to [3.3.10p2] (quote below), the variable `i` hides the `struct`.

> A class name (9.1) or enumeration name (7.2) can be hidden by the name
>   of a variable, data member, function, or enumerator declared in the
>   same scope. If a class or enumeration name and a variable, data
>   member, function, or enumerator are declared in the same scope (in any
>   order) with the same name, the class or enumeration name is hidden
>   wherever the variable, data member, function, or enumerator name is
>   visible.

So, the code is well-formed and Clang is wrong to reject it.

MSVC (12 and 14) accepts the example.

---

Basically, think of the name introduced by a *using-declaration* as just another name for some entity, which is also named somewhere else (the place designated by the *nested-name-specifier* of the *qualified-id* in the *using-declaration*). This is different from what a *using-directive* does; I tend to think of *using-directives* as "name lookup tweaks".

Comment: The closeness of the terms *using-declaration* and *using-directive* doesn't help understanding I'm sure... :)

Comment: @Barry Very true. And, in classic C++ style, both of them do more than one thing depending on context. Not to mention the `using` keyword itself, which is even more heavily overloaded.