# May this kind of rewrite of placement new compile?

Tags: c++, placement-new

**Background**

I am cleaning up a legacy codebase by applying a coding guideline for the `new` statement.

There is code like `auto x = new(ClassName);` that I rewrite to `auto x = new ClassName();`. It's quite obvious that this is not a placement new and I don't need to think about it.

However, there's also code like `auto x = new(ClassName)(argument);` which looks much like a placement new. For now I blindly rewrote such code to `auto x = new ClassName(argument);` as well.

**Question**

Might there be a case where a real placement new like `auto x = new(placement-params)(Type);` is rewritten as `auto x = new placement-params(Type);` and it still compiles but changes the meaning of the program?

Comment: The parentheses in `new(ClassName)` are just like parentheses around any general expression. And in this case they are simply not needed. The expression `new(ClassName)` is exactly equivalent to `new ClassName`. From this it should be quite clear that `new(ClassName)(argument)` is exactly the same as `new ClassName(argument)`, which is what you already translated it as.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I'm sorry to disagree. You can't simply add arbitrarily many parentheses in `new(A)` like you do for a calculation. These parentheses do not behave like in any expression. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new and https://godbolt.org/z/KK7eqY9s4. Also, that wasn't my question. The question is about a similar rewrite for a real placement new.

Comment: @ThomasWeller see (1) here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new note the "extra" brackets.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You comment reminds me of last weeks : C++ weekly. ;)

Comment: @RichardCritten: yes, I know that `new(ClassName)` is valid syntax, but that's not the question. The question is whether rewriting an actual placement by removing the parens may result in compilable code that does something else.

Comment: Without a concrete example I don't think we can help if you already know the syntax.

Comment: @RichardCritten: if I knew an example, I needn't ask the question.

Comment: BTW: `auto x = new(ClassName)` is not the same as `auto x = new ClassName();` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new

Comment: Looking here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new , it seems like `new (A)` is a placement new when `A` is a value, but not when it is a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`placement-params` is not a type, it is a value.

Consider this code with a placement new:

```
int* buf = new int;
int* a = new(buf)(int);
```

If we remove parenthesis around `buf`, the compiler can easily detect `buf` is not a type.

```
int* a = new buf(int); // compile error
```

Even if we create a type named `buf`, by [the name lookup rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup), the name in the inner scope is found first:

```
class buf {         // found second
    buf(int) {}
};

int main() {
    int *buf = new int;  // found first
    int* a = new buf(int); // compile error
    return 0;
}
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31711699/2527795), when type and value are in a same scope, the value is found first. For example:

```
class buf {         // found second
    buf(int) {}
};
int *buf = new int;  // found first

int main() {
    int *a = new buf(int);  // compile error
    return 0;
}
```